# Switched to Debian 6, but still have home encrypted

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I was thinking of going back to Debian, because of old times.

So I did a fresh install on my computer.

And tweaked my login-name as well

What id totaly forgot was that i have encryption

on my home in ubuntu

And now im stuck without all my documents and other stuff

How can i get it back?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start by installing this package

> ecryptfs-utils

and run `ecryptfs-setup-private`

It will ask for your passphrase and you'll be able to mount your Private directory with `mount.ecryptfs_private`

Comment: seems that i dont have the neccesary modules in the kernel, and i dont have/know the passprase either... (as i know it anyway)

Comment: seems that i dont have the neccesary modules in the kernel, and i dont have/know the passprase either... (what i know of it anyway) i just want to have my files unencrypted then thats good enough for me as i also have another login-name i dont want to make things more advanced than they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

One sollution could be to do another install (again) with ubuntu and choose to encrypt and then when the installation is finished to deactivate encryption and then install what system i want again.... so 2 reinstalls... can that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to boot an Ubuntu LiveCD, and run [ecryptfs-recover-private](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-recover-private) to recover your documents and data in the clear, and then move them over to your Debian system.

Note that Debian does have decent support for eCryptfs, though it's not quite as fully integrated as Ubuntu.

*Full disclosure: I am one of the authors and the current maintainer of the eCryptfs userspace packages and project.*